# how to run PHP in a Angualr2 CLI

Tags: php, angular2-template

I am using Angular2 CLI for my frontend framework and using PHP for my backend.

```
    this.http.post('assets/modify.php', '')
    .subscribe(result => {
        console.log("success post php file");
      }
    );
```

I want to use post method to run modify.php. However, I got error: 
POST XXXXX/assets/modify.php 404 (Not Found)

I can use get method to read the PHP with the same URL, it is working fine. But how can I use Post to run the PHP.

modify.php:

```
<?php

//lode the file
$contents = file_get_contents('button.json');

//Decode the JSON data into a PHP array.
$contentsDecoded = json_decode($contents, true);

//Modify the counter variable.
$contentsDecoded['button1Status'] = "booked";

//Encode the array back into a JSON string.
$json = json_encode($contentsDecoded);

//Save the file.
file_put_contents('button.json', $json);

?>
```

The folder structure is:

app------ user---------------  user.component.ts(I am runing get or post method here)

assets----button.json
          modify.php

when I use get method :

Request URL:http://localhost:4200/assets/modify.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

when I use post method:

Request URL:http://localhost:4200/assets/modify.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

---

**Just for a update from people's help.

I found this and it help me figure out what happened to my scenario:

[executing php files in a angular2cli app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465263/executing-php-files-in-a-angular2cli-app)

SO I am thinking at the development stage, I need to have a web server can run PHP code.Will have a try on the build-in PHP Server.**

Comment: where are your php scripts located? I doubt they are in 'assets' (where things like css should be I suppose). You just need to get the link right.

Comment: @jeff yes, php scripts is located at assets. see my updated. the get method can load it, but post method return a 404 error

Comment: Your GET request may be working but I bet it's not executing your PHP script. Instead, it's probably returning the PHP source code.

Comment: @PHIL you are right. get method is working, but seems like it only return the php source code. So how can I run the PHP code? I know I can use         $.ajax({
            url     : 'assets/modify.php',
            method  : 'post',
            success : function( ) {
                alert( "success" );
            }
        }); but what should I do for an angular2 application?It seems like ajax is not working here

Comment: following @Phil's comment I suppose you call your angular app via `file://yourpath/somethingelse`. You need to have a webserver running to serve your files vie `http://localhost:aPortMaybe/myApp`

Comment: You'll need an HTTP server that knows what to do with PHP files. For development purposes, you can use the [built-in PHP server](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php) though you may run into CORS issues with separate servers

Answer (score 0):

Try fully qualifying or at least a good relative URL.  I'm going to assume assets is at your docroot, if not then adjust that root slash accordingly:

eg:

```
/assets/modify.php
```

or:

```
https://mywebhost/assets/modify.php
```

Your example PHP file doesn't seem to care about anything being sent to it, why use the POST method in the ajax, why not just use GET?

Comment: Hey, I have very limit knowledge regarding Angular and PHP. Yes ,  the PHP file doesn't care about anything being sent to it. What I need to do is to run this PHP ? How to use Post method:    
  this.http.post('assets/modify.php', "")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
 I still got 404 error not found. But when I use get method. the php is successfully loaded with the same URL

Comment: Did you try to fully quality the path / URI you're posting too?

    this.http.post('/assets/modify.php',"");   

The 404 means it can't resolve the location of that resource, and the only think I can think of right now is that   you need to fully qualify it.